# what is ARGV in ruby and what does it do?

Tags: ruby

What is `ARGV` and how do I use it?

Comment: also what is the difference between ARGV and ARGV.first?

Comment: You are trying to `Learn ruby the hard way` and you are taking the easy way out just asking people how to do it. This is not the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARGV is basically an array that contains the elements passed to your script. You may find [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329132/whats-the-point-of-argv-in-ruby) useful.

To test it, try creating .rb (let's say it's "test.rb") file in specific folder and put the following code there:

```
puts ARGV.inspect
```

Now, try opening a command line window/terminal and point it to the folder where "test.rb" is. Once you're there, type this in your terminal:

```
ruby test.rb a 1 b
```

You should get `["a", "1", "b"]` which is the content of `ARGV`.